# plsqlにおける=>の意味を知りたい

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

plsqlを勉強しています。
現場のコードに以下のようなものがありました。

> プロシージャ名(   引数名A       => 引数);

この **=>** は何を示しているでしょうか？
引数への値の設定だと思うのですが。
ドキュメントはありますでしょうか？
探していても検索方法が難しくなかなかヒットしません

Comment: 蛇足ではありますが、Google search engine で検索語を `plsql what name operator "=>" :site stackoverflow.com` にして検索すると、[PL/SQL mysterious arrow operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422072/pl-sql-mysterious-arrow-operator) が引っ掛かります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使ったことはないですが、検索するに

`名前表記法 (Named Notation)` と呼ばれているもののようです。
おそらく他の言語でいうところの`名前付き引数`に相当するものとだと思います。

> 探していても検索方法が難しくなかなかヒットしません

`=>`は検索しにくいですが、こういうときは、かわりに `arrow` で検索すると良いです。

> 引数への値の設定だと思うのですが。

ご推測のとおりの動きだと思います。

> ドキュメントはありますでしょうか？

下記参考資料1番目にドキュメントへのリンクがありますが、念の為ここにも記載しておきます。
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm#sthref1013

参考:

- [oracle - PL/SQL mysterious arrow operator - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422072/pl-sql-mysterious-arrow-operator)
- [位置表記法と名前表記法 - オラクル・Oracle PL/SQL 入門](https://www.shift-the-oracle.com/plsql/positional-named-notation.html)
- [[ORACLE] 引数名を指定してファンクション、プロシージャを呼び出す | ORACLE逆引きノート](https://oracle.programmer-reference.com/oracle-argument-name/)

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。名前付き引数に相当するものなのですね。アロー演算子も検索したような気もするのですが見つけれず、やはり英語の文献のほうが豊富なので、英語での検索をするようにした方がいいでしょうか。おそらくそうだと思いますので、これからヒットしない際は英語での検索をするように致します。ご自身はやはり英語で検索するようにされていらっしゃるのでしょうか。教えて頂きありがとうございました。

Comment: そうです。基本的には英語で検索するようにしております。はじめはキツイですが、慣れるとできるようになってきます（慣れたとしてもキツさは残ります。やはり日本語の方が圧倒的に楽ですが、仕方ないですね...）

Comment: ありがとうございます。英語での検索心がけます。慣れていきます！